# Issues with Powershell Remoting

Tags: windows, powershell, remoting

I'm configuring a new network and i need to enable Powershell Remoting.
I'm in an Active Directory Domain and all my Clients are connected to the Domain.

I'm able to run remote commands (Get-Process -Computername A1P1) successfully but i can't do One-to-One remoting (new-pssession -cn A1P1)

Steps i've Taken:

- winrm quickconfig
- Enable-PSRemoting
- GPO to configure remoting
- Enabled RemoteRegistry
- Setting TrustedHosts to * on the Management Station and Clients

The winrm service is running and ports are open.

Any Tips?

Edit: I Just realized i was once able to remotely connect to my server but i can't now. This is the errorId: **WinRMOperationTimeout,PSSessionOpenFailed**

Edit 2: It's a GPO Issue, i tried disabling it and gpupdating and the listener now works fine (after Enable-PSRemoting). Now i need to find the setting that's causing the problem...

Comment: If it's not firewall, it's likely a mismatch security setting between server/client. I would pay attention to computer\windows settings\security settings\local policy\security options. Usual suspects include communication signing, NTLM session security level, LAN Manager authentication level, etc. Settings in "User rights" are worth checking too.

Comment: What's the output of `winrm e winrm/config/listener`?

Comment: Did you configure allowed IP ranges?

Comment: You shouldn't need to manipulate trustedhosts anywhere if both client and server is joined to the same AD.

Comment: Dig into all of your GPO's and disable 1 at a time and test/verify. I've came across a GPO that caused a unrelated side affect before. Just disable, gpupdate /force and try again. Enable and check firewall logging for both allowed and blocked connections and see what it's doing. Also in the system logs check to see what it says at the time that you tried connecting. It may shed some light as well.