# WinRM failing when attempted from Win10, but not from WSE2016

Tags: windows, powershell, hyper-v, windows-server-essentials, remoting

I'm unable to `PSRemote` to my Hyper-V host, nor can I connect to it using Hyper-V Manager. This occurs from a client VM, but not the server VM. I can `PSRemote` and connect without problem from the server.

This is my setup:

- [HOST] is Hyper-V 2016
- [SERVER] is a Server Essentials 2016 VM
- [CLIENT] is a domain-joined VM, running Windows 10 v1607
- I'm signed into both [SERVER] and [CLIENT] under the domain admin account

**Error Message:**

> Enter-PSSession : Connecting to remote server [HOST] failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot complete
>   the operation. Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the network, and
>   that a firewall exception for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer. By default, the WinRM
>   firewall exception for public profiles limits access to remote computers within the same local subnet. For more
>   information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

**[HOST] Firewall Configuration:**

[image]

**Troubleshooting Steps:**

- I've set the WinRM firewall entry on [HOST] to `All` profiles and `Any` remote address
- I've disabled the firewall on [HOST] entirely
- I've scoured the troubleshooting steps found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_troubleshooting?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- I've successfully run this command on [HOST]: `C:\>winrm set winrm/config/client @{TrustedHosts="CLIENT"}`
- I've successfully run this command on [HOST]: `PS C:\> Enable-PSRemoting -Force`
- I've started the WinRM service on [CLIENT]
- I've reviewed [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/709970/cant-connect-hyper-v-server-2012-r2-after-windows-10-update) Q&A, but the suggestions provided there don't work for me.
- I've reviewed all of the Q&A [here](https://serverfault.com/search?q=winrm+psremoting), but none apply directly. The closest I found was [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/703071/issues-with-powershell-remoting), but I'm not sure how to temporarily disable GPO on [CLIENT] as described.

The WinRM event log on [CLIENT] shows these errors:

**Command:**

`Get-WinEvent -LogName Microsoft-Windows-WinRM/Operational -MaxEvents 10 | Where-Object {$_.LevelDisplayName -eq "Error"} | fl`

**Result:**

```
TimeCreated  : 3/18/2017 12:43:46 PM
ProviderName : Microsoft-Windows-WinRM
Id           : 142
Message      : WSMan operation CreateShell failed, error code 2150859046

TimeCreated  : 3/18/2017 12:43:46 PM
ProviderName : Microsoft-Windows-WinRM
Id           : 161
Message      : WinRM cannot complete the operation. Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the
               computer is accessible over the network, and that a firewall exception for the WinRM service is enabled
               and allows access from this computer. By default, the WinRM firewall exception for public profiles
               limits access to remote computers within the same local subnet.

TimeCreated  : 3/18/2017 12:43:46 PM
ProviderName : Microsoft-Windows-WinRM
Id           : 138
Message      : The client got a timeout from the network layer (ERROR_WINHTTP_TIMEOUT)
```

This also occurred before I upgraded both [HOST] and [SERVER] from 2012R2 to 2016, so it leads me to believe that it's something on [CLIENT].

Oddly, I was temporarily able to connect from [CLIENT] immediately after the upgrade. I don't recall whether that was before I turned on the default security GPO on [SERVER] and imported my custom (non-security-related) GPO settings from backup; perhaps it might be related to that?

Is there a firewall rule on [CLIENT] that I need to create/enable? I can't turn the firewall off as a troubleshooting step, as it's managed by the default WSE GPO; as previously mentioned I don't know how to temporarily override that (or even if it's safe to do so).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I certainly wouldn't have expected *this* to be the answer...

On a whim, I tried connecting using the FQDN (e.g. `host.domain.tld`). To my surprise, it sailed right through, under both `Enter-PSSession` and Hyper-V Manager.

It might be something in the TCP/IP DNS settings on [CLIENT]. I'll have to check on that.

But for the time being, this does the trick.

**--EDIT--**

OK, got it.

The hosts file on [CLIENT] had a stale record with an outdated IP address for [HOST]. That's why WinRM would only work when I used the FQDN.

I removed the record and everything started working correctly immediately.